# MY dweller isnt happy

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, one of my dwellers just came back from exploration and his happiness is only at 10%. I put him back to full health, reduced his radiation and even made him have sex. But he is still at 10% and I don't know why. I've gotten him working at a place he is good at. And his wife is also working with him but he is still at 10%. What should I do? Should I wait for his happiness to climb up or is it gonna stay at 10%?